# Is the condition '[a value] reduces to [number]' fulfilled when the value reduces to less than the number?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, semantics

I am trying to deduce the nuances of the titular language for the purposes of a logic puzzle. To illustrate the specifics of the question, the following situation is provided.

Item A has a price of 40. Consider the following statement:

- When the price reduces to 30, I will buy the item.

The price of the item then reduces to 20. Interpreting the statement **literally** (and not trying to infer intent or implied meaning), according to the statement and situation provided, would the speaker buy the item?

As an alternative situation, consider the following:
The temperature outside is 30. We then have the similar statement:

- When the temperature reduces to 15, I will go outside.

Due to some unrelated supernatural weather phenomenon, the temperature suddenly then reduces to −15. Would the speaker go outside? The purpose of this second example is to try to demonstrate the different uses of this (albeit unnatural) language: **the answer to both questions must be the same**, since otherwise the interpretation is not separate to the (presumed) intentions of the speaker.

Finally, to rephrase the question in the abstract, for a statement forming a condition on when a value 'reduces **to**' a number, is that condition fulfilled when the value reduces to a **lesser** number? In other words, is the condition "[X] reduces to [Y]" ([X] was a value greater than [Y], and now it is [less than] [Y]) linguistically distinct in those specifics from the imperative or descriptive statement "[X] reduces to [Y]" ([X] was a value greater than [Y], and it **is now being reduced** to [Y])? The parenthetical '[less than]' is the crux of the question: should it be present?

Please include explanations of the specifics of the semantics where relevant: this is a question of specific definition and correct usage, not a question of understanding common parlance.

Comment: My apologies for the lengthy and possibly unclear question: this is my first time. :)

Comment: IMHO it is a bit ambiguous, but I would assume it means "30 or less". Probably something to take up with the puzzle setter.

Comment: If you think it's ambiguous (and you can support that assertion), I encourage you to leave an answer to that effect! Please heed the specifics of the question, though: I'm not asking for what *someone* means, I'm asking for what it **does** mean.

Comment: I'm not sure why you insist in the last paragraph that this is a grammar issue and have used the corresponding tag. It seems to me to be an issue of semantics, while the grammar is fairly straightforward.

Comment: My apologies. I welcome edits to the tags (or otherwise) if you feel I'm using them incorrectly! I'll change the tags as you suggest until I get other feedback.

Comment: The [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/grammar/info) is straightforward. You are asking about intention: there's no way anyone can determine intention. The puzzle setter may want you to interpret the statement literally, or he may want you to gauge human behaviour. "When the price reduces to 30, I will buy the item" may be interpreted as "The maximum I will pay is 30." I would observe that the item ***has*** reduced to 30; in fact it's gone even further.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Is your position that this question has no definite answer, even when attempting to take a prescriptive approach? The entire purpose of the question depends on ignoring the intention on the part of the speaker: if you think this *isn't possible,* an answer detailing as much would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: 'When the price reduces to $30' sounds unnatural to my ears, so I'd be predisposed against trying to read the mind of the setter anyway. 'When the price gets as low as $30' would always be taken as 'When the price falls to $30 or below'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I feel the language is unnatural and that this frustrates second guessing of the setter's intentions.

Comment: I will pay 30. When the price drops below that, I'm still buying and insisting on paying 30. But I'm buying. You'd have to reword to force the buyer not to buy at 30 **and below**.

Comment: ELU examines standard English usage. It is off-topic to ask about niche usage and over-literal insistence on selected definitions of words and phrases; that belongs, if anywhere, on a logic website. '[T]his is a question of ... correct usage, not a question of understanding common parlance' is self-contradictory. Usage drives acceptability in 
 standard English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is there a StackExchange community in which you think this question would better be asked?

Comment: Puzzling has a logic tag, and this might be on-topic there. But SE does not claim to address every legitimate type of question imaginable. There isn't a dedicated SE 'Logic' site (which would doubtless address the stipulative, non-everyday forced use of language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you insist on a clinically "sterile" approach with no regard for inference from context, only the "letter of the law" meaning of these words... **NO**. The phrase "reduce to [a given measurement]" simply means "reach [a given measurement, after having been higher]." It makes no implication about what happens next. In particular, if you start the assertion with "when," then you would seem to be pointing to that exact moment in time.

> When the temperature of water is reduced to 0 Celsius, ice crystals form.

In the strictest and most pedantic of interpretations, although of course we still get ice if we continue to lower the temperature, the phase change occurs at the exact moment of 0, not below.*

But meaning is not carried in individual words or phrases. Meaning is constructed, "at run time," by context. In your example, "I'll by when the price is reduced to 30," the most literal meaning is that you'll be standing with your money ready, and pounce the moment it ducks under $30.01. But a reasonable hearer might also suppose that you might not be watching the price every second, and should you discover that you missed "the moment" of 30, would still buy at 20.

On the other hand, if Dr. Emmett Brown promises us that when his DeLorean accelerates to 88 mph we will, ahem, travel through time, then one might reasonably assume that 89 would also suffice—but as we see it in action, since the time-travel occurs at the exact moment of 88 mph, one is never able to reach 89 before disappearing.

---

* This is probably terrible science. Supercooling is a thing, and I'm sure the ice formation isn't instantaneous. (Except when it is.) Just an illustration.

Comment: The second part of your answer seems to be treating the 'price' to be changing continuously, whereas in the example, the price was 40, and then, instantaneously, changed to 20 (such as if a 50% discount were to have been applied)—it never *was* 30. This is the crux of my question: would the specification 'drop to **exactly** 30' be necessary, or would it be redundant?
​
The first part of your answer seems to address this, though, and I'll accept it on that basis. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Fie Under that scenario, and using the strictest possible interpretation, then the conditional "When the price is reduced to 30" was never fulfilled. It was "reduced to 20." You said this is for a logic puzzle; perhaps the question is whether you want to be intentionally misleading? Because yes, a reasonable and casual hearer, who assumes the usual consumer motives of saving money etc., will infer a meaning of "I'll buy at 20," but you could call them wrong.

Comment: Part of why I included the specifications I did is because the question isn't intended to relate to *this* specific situation. The example could have instead (and perhaps should have) described a change in temperature (an arbitrary decrease in which isn't strictly desirable), an angle of firing, or some other quantity with which you might associate a number which can decrease in value.

Comment: @Fie Then I'll go with my overly-reductive definition: "reach [a given measurement, after having been higher]." And "when" means "at the moment that. By the way, I also forgot to mention, "X reduces to Y" is a bit of an awkward phrase in this scenario. It's not *wrong*, but many of these situations would more idiomatically use "X *is reduced to* Y." The non-reflexive version tends to be used more for conversions: "4/4 reduces to 1," "the broth reduces to a sauce."